# How can I export only some columns from that ADOQuery to Excel using Delphi (any version)?

Tags: excel, delphi, tadoquery

I have an ADOQuery (TADOQuery, bound to other visual components) with multiple columns (fields), in Delphi. I can export all the data (rows and columns) to an Excel file. I'm using OleVariant, something like ovRange.CopyFromRecordset (Data, Rows, Cols).
How can I export only some columns from an ADOQuery to Excel using Delphi (any version)?

```
procedure ExportRecordsetToMSExcel(const DestName: string; Data: _Recordset);
var
  ovExcelApp: OleVariant;
  ovExcelWorkbook: OleVariant;
  ovWS: OleVariant;
  ovRange: OleVariant;
  FileFormat: Integer;
  Cols, Rows: Cardinal;
begin
  FileFormat := ExcelFileTypeToInt(xlWorkbookDefault);
  ovExcelApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application'); // If Excel isnt installed will raise an exception

  try
    ovExcelWorkbook := ovExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add;
    ovWS := ovExcelWorkbook.Worksheets.Item[1]; // go to first worksheet
    ovWS.Activate;
    ovWS.Select;

    Rows := Data.RecordCount;
    Cols := Data.Fields.Count; // I don't want all of them, just some, maybe the ones that are visible

    ovRange := ovWS.Range['A1', 'A1']; // go to first cell
    ovRange.Resize[Rows, Cols]; //ovRange.Resize[Data.RecordCount, Data.Fields.Count];

    ovRange.CopyFromRecordset(Data, Rows, Cols); // this copy the entire recordset to the selected range in excel

    ovWS.SaveAs(DestName, FileFormat, '', '', False, False);
  finally
    ovExcelWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges := False);
    ovWS := Unassigned;
    ovExcelWorkbook := Unassigned;

    ovExcelApp.Quit;
    ovExcelApp := Unassigned;
  end;
end;
...
  ExportRecordsetToMSExcel('c:\temp\test.xlsx', ADOQuery.Recordset);
```

Resolved (working solution based on @MartynA and @PeterWolf's answers):

```
procedure ExportRecordsetToMSExcel(const DestName: string; ADOQuery: TADOQuery; const Fields: array of string); overload;

  procedure CopyData( { out } var Values: OleVariant);
  var
    R, C: Integer;
    FieldsNo: array of Integer;
    L1, H1, L2, H2: Integer;
    V: Variant;
    F: TField;
  begin
    L1 := 0;
    H1 := ADOQuery.RecordSet.RecordCount + L1 - 1;
    L2 := Low(Fields); // 0
    H2 := High(Fields);

    SetLength(FieldsNo, Length(Fields));
    for C := L2 to H2 do
      FieldsNo[C] := ADOQuery.FieldByName(Fields[C]).Index;

    Values := VarArrayCreate([L1, H1, L2, H2], varVariant);

    for R := L1 to H1 do begin
      for C := L2 to H2 do
        Values[R, C] := ADOQuery.RecordSet.Fields[FieldsNo[C]].Value;

      ADOQuery.RecordSet.MoveNext();
    end;
  end;

var
  ovExcelApp: OleVariant;
  ovExcelWorkbook: OleVariant;
  ovWS: OleVariant;
  ovRange: OleVariant;
  Values: OleVariant;
  RangeStr: string;
  Rows, Cols: Integer;
begin
  CopyData(Values);
  try
    ovExcelApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
    try
      ovExcelWorkbook := ovExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add;
      ovWS := ovExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

      Rows := ADOQuery.RecordSet.RecordCount;
      Cols := Length(Fields);
      RangeStr := ToRange(1, 1, Rows, Cols); // Ex: 'A1:BE100'

      ovRange := ovWS.Range[RangeStr];
      ovRange.Value := Values;

      ovWS.SaveAs(FileName := DestName);
    finally
      ovExcelWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges := False);
      ovWS := Unassigned;
      ovExcelWorkbook := Unassigned;

      ovExcelApp.Quit;
      ovExcelApp := Unassigned;
    end;
  finally
    VarClear(Values);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why not simply querying the database with a statement returning only the required fields?

Comment: The ADOQuery is bound to a visual control that shows multiple fields, and what I want is to export a set of these columns (whichever is specified). Also, the original query has many records, so it is not feasible to do it row by row. I have also tried using ADOQuery2.Clone (ADOQuery), but I have not been able to achieve it.

Comment: Forget the Excel sheet for a moment. Are you able to write all rows and columns with the fields you are interested in into a simple two dimensions array?

Comment: I can write the fields that interest me in a two-dimensional array, for example: ArrData:= VarArrayCreate(...);, and write the values. With that solution I can then directly write the array (Range.Value: = ArrayData). The disadvantage of this solution is that ADOQuery has many records, and the process would be very slow.

Comment: Use `DisableControls` on the `TDatset` when traversing the records, this will speed it up as the controls your dataset is connected to, are not updated on each row move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

I am obliged to Peter Wolf for the suggestion to use Excel's `Transpose` function to avoid the element by element copying in my initial code.  Trying to implement it, I found I ran into a known problem with `Transpose`, that it throws a "Type mismatch" error if it encounters a Null in the array it is transposing.  The updated code below has a work-around to this problem, and also removes a number of lines from the OP's code which seemed to me to be superfluous.

====

You can do what you are asking, without changing the SQL used to retrieve your recordset by using the recordset's `GetRows` method which is declared in AdoIntf.Pas as

```
function GetRows(Rows: Integer; Start: OleVariant; Fields: OleVariant): OleVariant; safecall;
```

This can retrieve the values from one or more named columns from the recordset into a variant array, as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-getrows-method-dao

A version of your routine modified to use `recordset.GetRows` might be

```
procedure ExportRecordsetToMSExcel(const DestName: string; Data: _Recordset);
var
  ovExcelApp: OleVariant;
  ovExcelWorkbook: OleVariant;
  ovWS: OleVariant;
  ovRange: OleVariant;
  Rows : Integer;
  FieldList : Variant;
  RSRows : OleVariant;
  i : Integer;
  Values : OleVariant;
begin
  ovExcelApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  ovExcelApp.Visible := True; //  So we can see what's happening
  try
    ovExcelWorkbook := ovExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add;
    ovWS := ovExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;


    //  RecordSet.GetRows (see AdoIntf.Pas) can return one or more fields of the RS to a variant array
    FieldList := 'Name';
    RSRows := Data.GetRows(Data.RecordCount, '', 'name' );

    //  The values from the RS 'Name' field are now in the 2nd dimension of RSRows
    //  The following is a naive way of extracting these values to a Transposable array
    Values := VarArrayCreate([VarArrayLowBound(RSRows, 2), VarArrayHighBound(RSRows, 2)], varVariant);
    Rows := VarArrayHighBound(RSRows, 2) - VarArrayLowBound(RSRows, 2) + 1;

    for i := VarArrayLowBound(RSRows, 2) to VarArrayHighBound(RSRows, 2)  do begin
      Values[i] := RSRows[0, i];

      //  Note:  the next 2 lines are to avoid the known problem that calling Excel's Transpose
      //         will generate a "Type mismatch" error when the array bring transposed contains Nullss
      if VarIsNull(Values[i]) then
        Values[i] := '';
    end;

    //  Now, transpose Values into the destination range (the 'A' column) using Excel's built-in function
    ovWS.Range['A1:A' + IntToStr(Rows)] := ovExcelApp.Transpose(Values);

    ShowMessage(' here');
  finally
    ovExcelWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges := False); //  Abandon changes to avoid tedium in debugging
    ovWS := Unassigned;
    ovExcelWorkbook := Unassigned;

    ovExcelApp.Quit;
    ovExcelApp := Unassigned;
  end;
end;
```

As noted in the code's comments, this extracts the `Name` column of the Sql table I happened to by using for this answer.

Please note R Hoek's comment about bracketing the call to your bound dataset's Open method by calls to `DisableControls` and `EnableControls`, as this will likely have as big an impact on speed as the method you use to import the column(s) into Excel.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `GetRows`. However copying rows one by one from the resulting array will be slow. Why not to write the whole array at once? Target range is `ovRange := ovWS.Range[ovWS.Cells[1, 1], ovWS.Cells[VarArrayHighBound(RSRows, 2) - VarArrayLowBound(RSRows, 2) + 1, VarArrayHighBound(RSRows, 1) - VarArrayLowBound(RSRows, 1) + 1]];`. Now you can assign the array to `Value2` of the range, but it will probably need transposing rows to columns: `ovRange.Value2 := ovExcelApp.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(RSRows);`.

Comment: I don't think `DisableControls` / `EnableControls` is really needed, because `GetRows` will not change active record of the dataset.

Comment: "Why not to write the whole array at once?"  Because the row values are in the 2nd column returned by GetRows, assigning the array in one go just doesn't work (otherwise I wold have done it).  IAC, the `for` loop executes virtually instantaneously using my test data (~5k rows).

Comment: "I don't think DisableControls / EnableControls is really needed"  It's not for speeding up `GetRows`, but rather for the call to the recordset's owner's `Open`.

Comment: Note the use of `Transpose` function in my comment to match the shape of the target range. Besides that you only copy single column while the question indicates copying multiple columns. I did a quick test with 5K rows with single column and copying of individual values was ~10 times slower compared to writing the values to range in one step. The key to speed is to minimize calls to methods of automation object.

Comment: "Iterate" is a solution that is not desired, specifically for performance (number of rows and columns). Otherwise, I could directly iterate each ADOQuery record and take only the fields (columns) that are desired.
On the other hand, the idea proposed by Peter Wolf (use of the Transpose) would seem correct, from a performance point of view. The problem with that solution is that apparently .Transpose() transposes a single row (or column) array. Or not? In my case, several rows/columns should be transposed.

Comment: Well, maybe, but you didn't actually answer my query about how many dataset records are you dealing with.

Comment: Some tables have 450K records (~250 fields), while others are around 55M records (~10 fields). ADOQueries get data from multiple "joined" tables, so sometimes many rows/columns are generated.

Comment: @PeterWolf:  Many thanks for the help, i've updated my answer to use `Transpose`.  I'm still struggling with the Q I posted yesterday evening about how to get a similar result while avoiding `Transpose` ...

Comment: @Elton:  See my updated answer - it does no iteration on the source of the RecordSet, and reduces to number of automation calls from X (= number of recordset rows, in my case about 5k) to 1.

Comment: @MartynA: With the proposed solution, the "Type mismatch" error has been eliminated; thank you.
In my case, it is not only one field that I want to export, but several.

Answer (score 0):

You can set or change the definition of a query , for example AdoQouery2  ,as below:

```
if AdoQouery2.active then
 AdoQouery2.close ;
AdoQouery2.sql.clear ;
AdoQouery2.sql.add ( 'Select filed1 , filed2 ,... from table1') ;
AdoQouery2.open ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).